# My getElementId is null (javascript native)

Tags: javascript, dom, bulma

I have a silly problem I think, but I've tried several answers found on the net and nothing works so far. 
I'd just like to have an `id=modal`

Here's the code:

```
   <html lang="fr">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Le Cabinet</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo-min.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-
      awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-sheet.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.scss">
      </head>
         <body>
          <main>
            <div class="container">
              <section class="columns"> 
                <div>
                 <button onclick="toggleClass()" class="button is-rounded is-info is-hidden-tablet section__btn__info">Plus d’infomartions...</button>
                  <div id="modal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-background"></div>
                    <div class="modal-card">
                      <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <p class="modal-card-title modal__title"></p>
                      </section>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </main>
        </body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/burger.js"></script>

</html>
```

script:

```
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
console.log('modal', modal);

function toggleClass() {
  modal.classList.toggle('is-active');
}
```

And modal return `null`,I can't get the `id`.

[image]

Comment: I can't see `modal__cabinet` id in your markup.

Comment: There is no HTML with `#modal__cabinet`.

Comment: sorry i edited my code

Comment: where is that script? in the same file? or a different one?

Comment: it's another file:   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/burger.js"></script>

Comment: What result do you expect ?

Comment: In the end I want to change this id with toggle... but for the moment I would like to get it back and when I `console.log(modal)` it returns `null`.

Comment: What expect in console.log

Comment: @Mamun I'm waiting for the id to be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you inject/insert your script.

You have to inject/insert your script at the bottom of your body, because when you call document.getElementById if the script is at the top, the html is not load so we can't find your id like :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- My super html -->
    <script src="path/to" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've integrated it into `<head>`. And in' body' I have a new error: `Identifier 'modal' has already been declared`. I think I could find a solution with that.

Comment: You have to delete your insert/inject script in your head, you have a conflict because you insert/inject the same JS file so your const modal is declared in the head file and the body file.

Comment: @BenoitChassignol Indeed I forgot to delete the one in the header, however the id is still null :( :( :(

Comment: This is not a best practice to inject some inline script on your HTML.

Comment: @mathiasF can you post your full html and js files ?

Comment: I think you need to read some documentation about injection of Javascript in HTML. There is a ggod article here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html

Comment: @BenoitChassignol I edited my question. I would actually like that when I click on the button his modal id changes

Comment: And this is my console: `modal null`, `Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

Comment: I don't see where you have insert your Js file ?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol I can insert it like you in body or just after the two doesn't work. ( edited my question again)

Comment: @BenoitChassignol whatttt. :( I really don't understand. Thank you for your patience. I'm gonna keep looking for where the problem comes from.

Comment: I have reproduce your bug, this is not for blame you but are you sure to have insert the JS file at the end of your body, save your file and refresh your browser page ?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol I took a screenshot and added it to the question.

Comment: Save your file and refresh your page ? If it still not work I don't understand.